# ffmpegthumbnailer -t not working as expected

Tags: carrierwave, video-thumbnails, ffmpegthumbnailer

I'm trying to create a thumbnail 3 seconds into a mp4 video I've transcoded.

```
Running....ffmpegthumbnailer -c jpg -q 10 -s 175 -t 00:00:03.0 -a -i /<FILEPATH>/thumb_20160816182847.MP4 -o /<FILEPATH>/tmpfile.jpg
```

The thumbnail is still showing second 0...what am I doing incorrectly?

The command is successful.